# How to send client specific trusted certificate authority for deciding which client certificates the user may use on the asp.net web form site

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis, ssl

I would like to create an asp.net web forms application which uses ssl client certificates. The way I understand it (which may be wrong), is that during the ssl handshake, the server sends the client a list of trusted certificate authorities.  The client then uses this list to see which CA's it also trusts and then the web browser asks the user which client certificate it would like to use (if there is more than 1 for a matching CA).

Is there a way to add code to the ASP.NET web application so only 1 specific CA gets sent down as being trusted? I assume the server will have many of the popular CA's as being trusted and sends them all down; but I just want to send down a specific one to the client.

Comment: @MickyDuncan, it is actually how the protocol works, but it is not used.  The functionality is [disabled by default with W8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsnotes/archive/2015/05/25/wcf-certificate-trust-list-ctl-issue-with-window-server-2012-r2-and-window-8-1.aspx), and was [broken with IIS 5,6 and 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2007/12/07/certificate-trust-list-not-being-honored-by-iis-5-0-6-0-7-0.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The negotiation of client certificate happens before ASP.Net gets involved in the request.  The configuration is on the HTTP.sys listener via [Certificate Trust Lists](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/06/11/how-to-create-custom-certificate-trust-list-in-windows-server-2k8-r2.aspx).

However, this behavior is ignored by [IIS 5, 6, and 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2007/12/07/certificate-trust-list-not-being-honored-by-iis-5-0-6-0-7-0.aspx), and has been [disabled by default on Windows 8 / 2012 and later](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsnotes/archive/2015/05/25/wcf-certificate-trust-list-ctl-issue-with-window-server-2012-r2-and-window-8-1.aspx).